# Does MERGE statement can benefit from BigQuery field clustering?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sql-optimization

I merge two tables in Google BiqQuery ON several `STRING` fields

(`field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`).

Will `MERGE` query be more efficient if I cluster my tables on `field_1`?   `field_1`, `field_2`? All 4 fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no optimization (yet) for joining clustered tables using merge join instead of hash join, so no. Clustering provides significant performance improvements with filters and aggregations using the cluster keys, however.

Comment: Are there any updates to this?

Comment: I left BigQuery for Snowflake a couple of years ago. Maybe post a new question.